# MongoDB Data Fetch and Insert ChartJs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, chart.js

I have a document model in MongoDB

{  _id:
author:
title:
content:
}

Collection name: posts

How can I group distinctly author names and count how many documents exist in my collection related to unique author names

Then ı want to insert this data to chartjs in my app

Is there any good Node/MongoDB developer could you please help me ?
I can also share my screen ıf you message me

Best Regards

I could not find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using aggregate. Something like below:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {$group: { _id : "$author", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Comment: That works,  great thanks !
Then ı need to assign the result of this query to an array
and use this array in chartjs label - data area 
I hope ı can do that :/

Comment: Yes. we can do that. If you face any issue while doing that you can always create another post here in SO. If this answer helped you, please upvote and mark it as approved. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Dear CodeThing,  could you please check my new post  ı explained my problem more detailed,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76314844/nodejs-application-charjsmongodb-problem