# NodeJS Application Charjs+MongoDB Problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, chart.js, backend

NodeJS Application - MongoDB

I have a problem , ı am trying to create a chart via ChartJS framework.
[MongoDB Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YznXU.png)

I want to run this query in this code block which belongs appjs file

```
`
app.get("/leaderboard", function (req, res) {
  Post.find({}).then((posts) => {
    res.render("leaderboard", { posts: posts });
  });
});
`
```

Then ı want to create a chart using ChartJS script defining labels & data arrays.
I will try to add author information which we get with mongo query into labels array
I will try to add count information which we get with mongo query into data array

```
`<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels:[],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Count of Shared Posts by Author Name",
            data: [],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  </script>`
```

If anyone can help ı can share my discord account and we can check together...

I could not create a graph.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you